# Adding string which starts with single quotes to excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I was trying to automate text to column function, delimited with space in excel through VBA.

```
strArray = split (currentSheet.Cells(i,1).Value), " ")

For j = 0 To (UBound(strArray) - LBound(strArray))
       currentSheet.Cells(i, 1 + j).NumberFormat = "@"
       currentSheet.Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = strArray(j)
Next j
```

The issue encountered when i get some text like: **KIDS 'R' KIDS**

The second word **'R'** is becoming **R'** in the cell, however if I do in build text to column function in excel with space as delimiter this word comes as 'R' only in the cell.

If I add one more single quotes in the beginning **''R'** the problem resolves, but I think this may affect my further processing of data.

So is there any way around?

Comment: if we assume this is in A1 and using "KIDS 'R' KIDS" what would you expect the result to be? A2 = "KIDS" A3 = "'R'" A4 = "KIDS" ?

Comment: try replacing all the single quotes by chr(39) before splitting.

Comment: @99moorem Yes.. You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the TextToColumns VBA functionality - it retains the `'`.  This code will only work on a single cell rather than a range.

```
Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        TextToCols .Range("A1"), .Range("B1")
    End With
End Sub


'Comments indicate how to add a blank column between words.
Public Sub TextToCols(DataRange As Range, Optional DestinationRange As Range)

    Dim nElements As Long
    Dim vFieldInfo As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    If DataRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        'Add an extra space to each space (1 space becomes 2).
        DataRange = Replace(DataRange, " ", "  ")

        If DestinationRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DestinationRange = DataRange
        End If

        nElements = Len(DataRange.Value) - Len(Replace(DataRange.Value, " ", ""))

        ReDim vFieldInfo(1 To nElements)
        For x = 1 To nElements
            vFieldInfo(x) = Array(x, 1)
        Next x

        'Add ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False to the TextToColumns.
        DataRange.TextToColumns _
            Destination:=DestinationRange, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Space:=True, _
            FieldInfo:=vFieldInfo

        'Remove the extra space (2 spaces becomes 1)
        DataRange = Replace(DataRange, "  ", " ")

    End If

End Sub
```

Returns this:
[image]

With an extra space between words and `ConsecutiveDelimiter` set to false it returns this:
[image]

This block of code allows you to pass a text string to the `TextToCols` procedure.  You could combine the code to accept either a range or text string but that would be a fair amount of extra code.
I've added comments to show where I've changed the code from the original.

```
Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        TextToCols "Kids 'R' Kids", .Range("B1")
    End With
End Sub


Public Sub TextToCols(TextToSplit As String, _
                      DestinationRange As Range)

    Dim nElements As Long
    Dim vFieldInfo As Variant
    Dim x As Long
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim DataRange As Range

    'Add a temporary worksheet to perform the split on.
    Set wrkSht = DestinationRange.Parent.Parent.Worksheets.Add
    wrkSht.Cells(1, 1) = TextToSplit
    Set DataRange = wrkSht.Cells(1, 1)

    'Don't need this line anymore as a text string will never be counted in cells.
    'If DataRange.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        'Add an extra space to each space (1 space becomes 2).
        DataRange = Replace(DataRange, " ", "  ")

        'Can remove this code block as DestinationRange
        'can't be optional with a text string - we need somewhere to paste the data.
'        If DestinationRange Is Nothing Then
'            Set DestinationRange = DataRange
'        End If

        nElements = Len(DataRange) - Len(Replace(DataRange, " ", ""))

        ReDim vFieldInfo(1 To nElements)
        For x = 1 To nElements
            vFieldInfo(x) = Array(x, 1)
        Next x

        'Add ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False to the TextToColumns.
        'Note: DestinationRange is always the same sheet as DataRange.
        '      Even if DestinationRange is pointing to another sheet, it will split
        '      to the address but on the DataRange sheet.
        DataRange.TextToColumns _
            Destination:=DestinationRange, _
            DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
            Space:=True, _
            FieldInfo:=vFieldInfo

        'This line looks at the correct DestinationRange address but on the temp sheet.
        'It then resizes that range to however many cells were split to and copies that
        'to our real destination.
        DataRange.Parent.Range(DestinationRange.Address).Resize(, x).Copy _
            Destination:=DestinationRange

        'Can remove this line as well - the whole sheet is deleted after the split.
        'Remove the extra space (2 spaces becomes 1)
        'DataRange = Replace(DataRange, "  ", " ")

    'End If

    'Delete the temporary sheet.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wrkSht.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly for me.Just need one help on this. I'm trying to get the result populated in every alternate cells. In this eg the result should come in B, D, F columns. Is there any way?

Comment: For that I'd add an extra space between the words and tell the text to columns not to treat consecutive delimiters as one.  I'll update my code.

Comment: Is it possible to sent a string instead of the address of the cell?   like TextToCols teststring, .Range("B1")

Comment: `TextToColumns` must take a range object so you can't just pass a text string to it.  But you can perform a bit of a hack - create a temporary sheet, paste the text into that, split it and then copy and paste to your destination cell.  I've added a second code block to show this.

Comment: I had to do some more data manipulations before the textocolumns without changing the original cell. That's why I asked. Any way I have figured out a way. I just formatted the text in the way I wanted and put in the destination cell and used textocolumns from there. Thanks @darren for the help. It helped a lot.

Comment: Now one more issue came up. When I did the text columns the many dates and large numbers in my data has been getting formatted by excel automatically. I tried changing the sheets number format to text by using `currentSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"` still dint work

Comment: Do you have an example of one of the text strings containing dates & large numbers?

Comment: PHARMACY 000007157     SAN MARCOS   CA
in this one the leading zeros are getting omitted

Comment: In the `For...Next` loop change `vFieldInfo(x) = Array(x, 1)` to `vFieldInfo(x) = Array(x, 2)`.  This will treat each column as text and retain the leading zeros.  For other formats refer to this link:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/xlcolumndatatype-enumeration-excel

Comment: No luck, still the leading zeros are getting truncated and larger numbers are changed to exponential format

Comment: Not sure then - when I've tried it it's kept the leading zeros and added the warning that it's a number formatted as text.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you would like "KIDS 'R' KIDS" like "KIDS", "'R'", "KIDS"

replace below

```
currentSheet.Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = strArray(j)
```

with

```
If Left(strArray(j), 1) = "'" Then
    currentSheet.Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = "'" & strArray(j)
else
    currentSheet.Cells(i, 1 + j).Value = strArray(j)
End If
```

Basically you analyse the text before outputting. as Excel will assume the first "'" is a special character and remove it.